# Like Button with Meta-tags

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I know this post must be pretty common, but I've been reading all around about the like button with meta-tags and all the sites says pretty much the same,

right now I'm working in an example just to see the post with format on my timeline

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="546941686"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="269696529779484" />
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:title" content="ShakeM PLayer" />
<meta property="og:description" content="ShakeM description about the new shake" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://shakemdev.brickmakers.de/Public/Images/shakem_logo.png" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://shakemdev.brickmakers.de/Multimedia/Player/Details/1133" />
```

and the code inside my body

```
<body>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=269696529779484";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://shakemdev.brickmakers.de/Multimedia/Player/Details/1161" action="like" data-send="false" data-width="200" data-show-faces="true" ></div>
```

this is the button and the result in my timeline, I can't see the title or description nor the image :( what I'm doing wrong this is a brand new html

http://impormaq.mx/like.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing one small point.  Facebook needs to have a div like:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

It is necessary to have this above your `<script>`.  I don't think facebook will work without it.

You may also need to have a call to the `FB.init()` funciton but I don't think it is always necessary.  So first try the `<div>`.